# determine the values of alpha for which the directional derivative exists in every direction

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm having trouble with the following problem:

let $$f(x,y)= \begin{cases} 
      \frac{x^3y^2z}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^\alpha} & (x,y,z)\neq (0,0,0) \\
      0 & (x,y,z)=(0,0,0)
   \end{cases}
$$ where $\alpha$ is a constant. Determine the values of $\alpha$ for which the directional derivative at $(0,0,0)$ exists for every direction $\hat{u}=(u_1,u_2,u_3)$.

Attempt:

Let $\hat{u}=(u_1,u_2,u_3)$ such that $\|\hat{u}\|=1$, we are looking for the values of $\alpha$ such that $$\lim_{t \to 0}  \frac{t^5}{(t^2)^\alpha}(u_1^3u_2^2u_3)$$ exists.

And $$\lim_{t \to 0}  \frac{t^5}{(t^2)^\alpha}(u_1^3u_2^2u_3)$$ exists for every direction $\hat{u}$ iff $$\lim_{t \to 0}  \frac{t^5}{(t^2)^\alpha}$$ exists. I don't understand, we saw a proof and the supposedly correct answer is:
if $\alpha<\frac{5}{2}$ the limit exists and it's equal to $0$; if $\alpha=\frac{5}{2}$ the limit depends of the side on which we approach, so the two sided limit cannot exist; finally, if $\alpha >\frac{5}{2}$ the limit diverges.

My question is: why in the second case ($\alpha=\frac{5}{2}$) doesn't the limit exist? I don't see why the answer depends on whether t is positive or t is negative.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Silly complaint: You mean directional derivative at $0$.

Comment: @TedShifrin yes I do, thank you very much. I already changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is, there is a difference between $(t^2)^{\frac{5}{2}}$ and $t^5$. To see this, note that $(-2)^5 = -32$ and $((-2)^2)^{\frac{5}{2}} = 4^{\frac{5}{2}} = 2^5 = 32$. While taking the square, the argument $t^2$ becomes positive, hence all it's powers are positive. However, $t^5$ can be negative whenever $t$ is negative.

Hence, the function $\dfrac{t^5}{(t^2)^{\frac{5}{2}}}$ has different signs for positive and negative $t$. Now, you can see that the limits from the positive and negative sides are $1$ and $-1$ respectively. That is why the limit does not exist.

Comment: I think I understand, thank you. You think it would be better then to notice that $\lim_{t \to 0}  \frac{t^5}{(t^2)^\alpha}= \lim_{t \to 0}  \frac{t^5}{(\mid t \mid^2)^\alpha}$?

Comment: Perfect. You have got the gist of my argument with that absolute value sign.

Comment: Okay, I think I understood. I'll be posting questions if they come up later. Again, thank you very much.

Comment: You are welcome, @ElDinosaurio